# UIControl with A Custom inputView in an Alert Level Window

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwindow, uiresponder

I've got a custom alert view, which appears in its own `UIWindow` with its `windowLevel` property set to `UIWindowLevelAlert`. The alert has a text field with a regular keyboard, and a custom `UIControl` subclass that returns a `UIDatePicker` as its `inputView`.

When the system presents the date picker in response to the control becoming first responder, the date picker appears *behind* the alert view. My solution to this was to adjust the picker's window's window level in the control's `reloadInputViews`:

```
- (void)reloadInputViews
{
    [super reloadInputViews];
    if (self.datePicker.window.windowLevel < self.window.windowLevel)
    {
        self.datePicker.window.windowLevel = self.window.windowLevel;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the app freezes when rapidly switching between the text field and the custom control (pausing the debugger reveals that the main thread is stuck on `mach_msg_trap`). I suspect that maybe its this trick with the window level, but I cannot verify.

Is there a more "correct" way to solve this problem? What is mach_msg_trap?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As so often happens, I figured it out shortly after posting...

As the `mach_msg_trap` instruction hints, this was a threading issue, unrelated to the implementation of the date picker control.

I fixed some `NSLock` objects elsewhere, which seems to have resolved the issue.